# SQL Server Service Broker Compatability across versions?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I'm planning a project to upgrade internally-developed app from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012. I hope to use Service Broker as a bridge while in transition. Are there any issues to consider in a forward-compatibility scenario like this other than newer features like multicasting not being present? I can't find anything in BOL specifically about compatibility.

Comment: What do you mean "use Service Broker as a bridge"?

Comment: Shimming in some triggers to catch DDL and sending the changes to the new system. We're changing several layers of the app stack at the same time- OS, SQL Version and Schema. The new system is under development and is planned to receive inputs via Service Broker anyway. During development, I would like send copies of incoming operational events to the 2012 instance to simulate production load.

Comment: So your triggers would be passing data to stored procedures on the new system, which happen to involve service broker on the new system. Not sure how service broker on 2005 is involved.

Comment: FWIW, I ran through the 2008R2 tutorial and it seems to work, though I had to grant some endpoint connect rights on the 2012 side. Bi-directional communication seems to work for simple cases, at least. I'll begin the implemetation and see what happens. I'd feel better I there was some sort of document stating the interop behaviour. BOL seems to have an attitude of "no major changes- should work...".

Comment: I think it probably SHOULD work because there's nothing being sent between the queues/services besides the messages themselves, and broker doesn't care at all about message formatting or content - it's just XML as far as the engine is concerned.

Comment: I want the triggers to stuff records into asynchronous queues, rather than getting into a cascading trigger mess.

Comment: Honestly the best way to tell is to set up two simple services with two queues and just see if you can send a message and get a response.

Comment: [Is Service Broker in SQL Server 2008/2012/2014 compatible with the one in SQL Server 2005?](http://rusanu.com/2007/11/28/is-service-broker-in-sql-server-2008-compatible-with-the-one-in-sql-server-2005/). the answer is that they are compatible, actually *they cannot be told apart*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can do cross SQL Server versions service broker as long as all instances are 2005 or newer, and only one of the instances can be SQL Server Express Edition.

Here are some helpful links:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/stuartpa/setup-secure-sql-server-service-broker-across-databases-in-less-than-10-seconds)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839483(v=sql.105).aspx